# Charting Software for Performance Stats

Tags: performance, graph, charts, visualization

I'm looking for a charting library similar to amCharts that allows you to create graphs with a timeline, e.g:

http://www.amcharts.com/stock/

It should also allow to you to select a range within the chart and zoom in to see further specifics.  The purpose of this is for visualizing performance related information such as i/o stats etc... Does anybody know of an open source library that will allow this?  A Ruby (most preferable) or Python library would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's going to be at all suitable for your needs, but recent "Communications of ACM" had an article about [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/). The graphics is very impressive. Still on my todo list though.